# plot multiple Datadog widgets based on same counter but different OpenTelemetry attributes

Tags: datadog, open-telemetry

For example, I have one counter, but 2 attributes:

```
counter := metric.Must(meter).NewInt64Counter("some-name")

attr1 := attribute.String("same-label-key", "different-label-value-1")
counter.Add(ctx, 1, attr1)

attr2 := attribute.String("same-label-key", "different-label-value-2")
counter.Add(ctx, 1, attr2)
```

The counter will be +2, in which `attr1` contributes +1, while `attr2` contributes another +1.

Is it possible for us to plot 2 different Datadog widgets (one widget for `attr1`, and another for `attr2`) based on the same counter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenTelemetry instrumentation and Datadog charts are at very different levels of abstraction.  You seem to be coupling them together in this question.  Datadog charting capabilities are independent of how the metric is actually instrumented in your app.  Similarly, how you instrument counters using OpenTelemetry is independent of how you chart those metrics (in Datadog or any other monitoring tool).

> Is it possible for us to plot 2 different Datadog widgets (one widget for attr1, and another for attr2) based on the same counter?

Yes, this is basic [filtering capability](https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/querying/#filter).  You would use the `from` clause in each widget and specify `different-label-value-1` and `different-label-value-2` respectively.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Just to double check, we do not need to create Views like what OpenCensus did to have the `from` tags popped up, right?